# ¿Cómo puedo mandar la información de un Form a un correo electrónico?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Quería saber como puedo mandar información de un `form` a un correo electrónico mi código es el siguiente:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px; background: #01A9DB;">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Sistema de Mensajeria</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form id="registration-form" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" action="MAILTO:andrewruiz.ruiz@gmail.com" enctype="text/plain">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="email">Direccion de Correo:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Su correo electronico" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="name">Nombre:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Su nombre" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="lastname">Apellido:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Su apellido" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="telephone">Telefono:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="Su telefono" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="telephone">Comentario:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="lastname">Pais, Ciudad</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                <select>
                    <option value='Afghanistan'>Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value='Aland Islands'>Aland Islands</option>
                    <option value='Albania'>Albania</option>
                    <option value='Algeria'>Algeria</option>
                    <option value='American Samoa'>American Samoa</option>
                    <option value='Andorra'>Andorra</option>
                    <option value='Angola'>Angola</option>
                    <option value='Anguilla'>Anguilla</option>
                    <option value='Antarctica'>Antarctica</option>
                    <option value='Antigua and Barbuda'>Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                    <option value='Argentina'>Argentina</option>
                    <option value='Armenia'>Armenia</option>
                    <option value='Aruba'>Aruba</option>
                    <option value='Australia'>Australia</option>
                    <option value='Austria'>Austria</option>
                    <option value='Azerbaijan'>Azerbaijan</option>
                    <option value='Bahrain'>Bahrain</option>
                    <option value='Bangladesh'>Bangladesh</option>
                    <option value='Barbados'>Barbados</option>
                    <option value='Belarus'>Belarus</option>
                    <option value='Belgium'>Belgium</option>
                    <option value='Belize'>Belize</option>
                    <option value='Benin'>Benin</option>
                    <option value='Bermuda'>Bermuda</option>
                    <option value='Bhutan'>Bhutan</option>
                    <option value='Bolivia'>Bolivia</option>
                    <option value='Bosnia and Herzegovina'>Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                    <option value='Botswana'>Botswana</option>
                    <option value='Bouvet Island'>Bouvet Island</option>
                    <option value='Brazil'>Brazil</option>
                    <option value='British Indian Ocean Territory'>British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                    <option value='British Virgin Islands'>British Virgin Islands</option>
                    <option value='Brunei'>Brunei</option>
                    <option value='Bulgaria'>Bulgaria</option>
                    <option value='Burkina Faso'>Burkina Faso</option>
                    <option value='Burundi'>Burundi</option>
                    <option value='Cambodia'>Cambodia</option>
                    <option value='Cameroon'>Cameroon</option>
                    <option value='Canada'>Canada</option>
                    <option value='Cape Verde'>Cape Verde</option>
                    <option value='Caribbean Netherlands'>Caribbean Netherlands</option>
                    <option value='Cayman Islands'>Cayman Islands</option>
                    <option value='Central African Republic'>Central African Republic</option>
                    <option value='Chile'>Chile</option>
                    <option value='China'>China</option>
                    <option value='Christmas Island'>Christmas Island</option>
                    <option value='Cocos (Keeling) Islands'>Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
                    <option value='Colombia'>Colombia</option>
                    <option value='Comoros'>Comoros</option>
                    <option value='Congo'>Congo</option>
                    <option value='Cook Islands'>Cook Islands</option>
                    <option value='Costa Rica'>Costa Rica</option>
                    <option value='Croatia'>Croatia</option>
                    <option value='Cuba'>Cuba</option>
                    <option value='Curacao'>Curacao</option>

                </select>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar Comentario!!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

No he realizado antes un envio de correos "contactanos" y deseaba saber como puedo hacer para que todos los registros que llene el usuario lleguen a un correo electrónico para que puedan ser leidos sus comentarios, ¿Alguien podría ayudarme? ¿Necesito configurar algo? ¿Puede ser solo con javascript? ¿Necesito php?

Comment: Evidentemente es muy facil enviar el mensaje por PHP pero en ocasiones no es posible usar PHP porque el server no cuenta con el y es necesario buscar alternativas? Entiendo la idea de usar javaScript en su lugar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu código es HTML. Lo que quieres hacer y mucha más funcionalidad estará a tu alcance cuando empieces a manejar algún lenguaje ejecutado por el servidor; como PHP, PERL o PYTHON.

Tu archivo index.php contendría el formulario.  Éste cuenta (como ya lo agregaste en tu código) con los atributos 'action' y 'method '. El primero recibe el nombre del archivo que procesará la información contenida en el formulario.  El segundo determinará el método de envío.  Asignando el valor de GET, la información (en forma de 'name=valor' para cada elemento del formulario) se pegará al final de la URL y será visible para el usuario.  Asignando el valor POST, la información llegará sin ser vista.

Utilizando PHP, toda la información de tu formulario será incorporada al array $_GET o al array $_POST como un array asociativo de donde puedes extraerla utilizando los nombres de tus inputs como keys de este array:

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];

El código suele escribirse en un segundo archivo, cuyo nombre se especifica en el atributo 'action' del formulario.  Si este atributo queda en blanco, el index.php se toma como default.

Finalmente, un objeto / instancia PHPMailer es el instrumento más completo para enviar correos electrónicos, como ya te explicaron más arriba.  Investiga sobre PHP primero, antes de profundizar en librerías.  No es muy difícil ni debería tomarte mucho tiempo.   Aunque por la fecha en que enviaste tu pregunta, ya debes de ser un experto en PHP!  :)

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres enviar correos, necesitas un lenguaje de server como php, en php puedes enviar correos usando la libreria phpmailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer, ademas de esto necesitas tener un servidor smtp para realizar el envio, puedes usar los servicios de smtp de google que es gratuito.

A continuación te pongo un ejemplo de como enviar correos a traves de smtp mediante el uso de esta libreria:

```
<?php
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Crea una instancia de PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Usar SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Habilitar el SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (para uso en produccion)
// 1 = mensajes del cliente
// 2 = mensajes del cliente y servidor
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

//Puerto SMTP puede ser 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 25;
//Usar Autenticacion
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Usuario para la autenticacion
$mail->Username = "yourname@example.com";
//Password para la autenticacion
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
//Quien Envia
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');

$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//A quien se va a enviar
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Asunto
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
//Cuerpo del mensaje
$mail->Body = "Hola, bienvenido!!!";
//Agregar Adjunto
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
//Enviar el mensaje revisando errores
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Mensaje enviado";
}
```

Comment: Como puedo acoplarle php a  mi proyecto? debo cambiar mis archivos .html a .php ? es decir si tengo index.html ahora seria index.php? como puedo mezclar estos entornos?

Comment: Son algunas cosas que se necesitan para trabajar en php, primero tienes que elegir un entorno de desarrollo, si estas en windows podrias usar XAMPP que viene con todas las herramientas para desarrollo con PHP, si estas en linux puedes instalar apache server y habilitar el soporte para php. No necesariamente tienes que cambiar a extension php tus archivos html, lo que tienes que hacer es dirigir el action del form a tu archivo php para que procese los datos del mismo. Te recomiendo ver el tutorial básico de la pagina oficial de php https://secure.php.net/manual/es/tutorial.php

Answer (score 3):

No se pueden enviar emails directamente con JavaScript, así que necesitarás un lenguaje del lado del servidor como PHP (el que sugieres).

Con JavaScript, lo que puedes hacer es abrir el cliente de correo electrónico del usuario usando el protocolo `mailto:`, pero no es muy recomendable porque 1) si el usuario no tiene ningún cliente de email configurado, no ocurrirá nada; y 2) si el usuario no pulsa el botón de enviar dentro del cliente de correo, la información no se enviará.

Con PHP, puedes enviar emails usando la función [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), que es muy sencilla (aunque también muy básica). El formato de `mail()` es el siguiente:

```
bool mail ( string $a , 
            string $asunto , 
            string $mensaje
            [, string $cabeceras adicionales
            [, string $parametros adicionales ]] 
          )
```

> Nota: para que funcione `mail()` necesitas que tener un servidor SMTP configurado

Así por ejemplo, para mandar un email que diga "Hola, caracola" a la dirección "test@test.com" y que tenga como asunto "Saludo", el código sería así:

```
mail("test@test.com", "Saludo", "Hola, caracola");
```

Un inconveniente de este método es que, como comentaba antes, es un poco básico y si quieres hacer algo más avanzado sería más conveniente usar alguna biblioteca/extensión ya existente como [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) o [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), que te facilitará la vida.